# Disable checkboxes by other checkboxes in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, checkbox, tkinter

I'm trying to create little desktop app. In main window I have four checkboxes, each checkbox has variable with value (0 for off, 1 for on):

```
random_cards = IntVar() 
random_stacks = IntVar() 
flip_cards = IntVar() 
wildcard = IntVar()

randomize_cards_checkbutton = Checkbutton(text="Randomize cards", variable=random_cards).grid(row=0, column=0, in_=options, sticky=W)
randomize_stacks_checkbutton = Checkbutton(text="Randomize stacks", variable=random_stacks).grid(row=1, column=0,in_=options, sticky=W)
wildcard_checkbutton = Checkbutton(text="Wildcard", variable=wildcard).grid(row=2, column=0, in_=options, sticky=W)
flip_cards_checkbutton = Checkbutton(text="Flip cards", variable=flip_cards).grid(row=3, column=0, in_=options, sticky=W)
```

I want the behavior to be that if `wildcard_checkbutton` is on, two checkboxes `randomize_cards_checkbutton` and `randomize_stacks_checkbutton` to be disabled (greyed out) and vice versa. I've written little function for this:

```
def check_checkbuttons(random_cards, random_stacks, wildcard):
    if wildcard == 1:
        randomize_cards_checkbutton.configure(state=DISABLED)
        randomize_stacks_checkbutton.configure(state=DISABLED)
    elif random_cards == 1 or random_stacks == 1:
        wildcard_checkbutton.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

Right now I don't know how to make this function run "all time". How do I implement it so this function is being checked all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, randomize_cards_checkbutton, and all the other checkbutton variables, equal None because that is what grid() returns.  For the checkbutton, use a "command=" to call the function when the state changes.  Note that you have to get() the Tkinter variable to turn it into a Python variable.  And any two buttons will work for this test/example, but each checkbutton will have a "command=" callback in the final program that will disable/enable what ever other checkbuttons you want it to.  At the minimum, use some print statements to help you debug.  A print statement would tell you what is None, and that wildcard is a PY_VAR, not an integer, etc.

```
def cb_check():
    if random_cards.get():
        randomize_stacks_checkbutton.config(state=DISABLED)
    else:
        randomize_stacks_checkbutton.config(state=NORMAL)

top=Tk()
random_cards = IntVar() 
random_stacks = IntVar() 
flip_cards = IntVar() 
wildcard = IntVar()

randomize_cards_checkbutton = Checkbutton(top, text="Randomize cards",
                              variable=random_cards, command=cb_check)
randomize_cards_checkbutton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

randomize_stacks_checkbutton = Checkbutton(top, text="Randomize stacks",
                               variable=random_stacks, bg="lightblue",
                               disabledforeground="gray")
randomize_stacks_checkbutton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

top.mainloop()
```